# Front End Will Not Open When Back End Encrypted

Tags: ms-access

I've been working on this database for a while. I have a development file on my PC and periodically I copy it, split the copy and set up the back end on a network path to test it 'in the wild'.

I've done this process several times, including relinking the tables on the front end after encrypting the back end with no problems. The back end would be encrypted and not accessible without a password and the front end connected to the back end as expected once it has been re linked using and the password supplied using the 'External Data > Access' tab (This is access 2013).

Today something's changed. I've written some queries and the DB's first report and decided to update the 'demo' version I have deployed on the network. I attempted the exact same procedure as usual (copy dev file, split the database, delete the links on the front end, exclusive open the back end, encrypt, re open the front end with the bypass key, re link, supply password).

However I couldn't re open the front end after encrypting the back end. I've spent the last couple of hours poking at the problem and found that no matter what I can't open the front end when the back end is encrypted. It doesn't matter if I have the linked tables present in the object navigator or not- the front end simply won't open if there's a password on the back end.

The rest of the database behaves as normal and throws out runtime errors when it can't find a table, but somehow even without the linked tables the front end 'knows' the back end is encrypted and will not open while it stays as such.

I've even tried splitting the database, deleting all the links and then reopening the front end. It opened fine but of course wouldn't work without the linked tables. I then encrypted the back end and attempted to re open the front end to add the links- no joy. I then decrypted the back end again just to see what would happen- back to square one with the front end now opening again.

Anyone know how I've screwed this up? Might it be related to the new queries and/or report?

As far as I can tell network permissions have not changed. If I don't encrypt the back end then I can still use the split front end and back end over the network.

Many thanks,

Comment: I've poked at the problem some more and found something else that might be helpful:

If I open two instances of access, one in the front end and one in the back end then I can leave the front end open as I encrypt the back end. I then re link the front end to the back end and am prompted for the password.

I can supply the password and then use the front as normal. Once I close the front end though I get the same problem and it refuses to open again.

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607611/ms-access-cant-link-to-encrypted-backend-database ? -- What exactly do you mean by "Cannot open the front end"? Error message? Code does not run?

Comment: I didn't see that one but I did eventually find this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419086/ms-access-frontend-wont-open-with-an-encrypted-backend

I didn't have to delete any tables but I did have to reveal the system tables (and probably the custom ribbon table specifically). Once I'd done that and gone through the split process everything worked.

For the record, the front not opening was literally that. No error message, no runtime errors, clicking the file simply caused access to open on its homepage.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see that one but I did eventually find this: stackoverflow.com/questions/47419086/… I didn't have to delete any tables but I did have to reveal the system tables (and probably the custom ribbon table specifically). Once I'd done that and gone through the split process everything worked. For the record, the front not opening was literally that. No error message, no runtime errors, clicking the file simply caused access to open on its homepage. – Evis03 Jan 3 at 10:13